# In Angular, How can we detect if DOM element has ngModel associated with it?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have an attribute directive that modifies the checked state of the host element. I'm using following code to do this:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private model: NgModel) {}

//OnInit code

if ('ng-reflect-model' in this.el.nativeElement.attributes) { <-- Problem is here, this attribute is available for debug, i want to put some condition here
  this.model.viewToModelUpdate(modelValue);
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(modelValue);
} else {
  this.el.nativeElement.checked = modelValue;
}
```

My problem is when the input has ngModel associated with it, I want to update the model if it is available otherwise update the checked state of native element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that i'm using presently is relying on `this.model.valueAccessor` property of NgModel class. If this attribute is absent then we can't access model value so no point in using it for update.

So my updated code is:

```
if (this.model.valueAccessor !== undefined && this.model.valueAccessor !== null) {
  this.model.viewToModelUpdate(modelValue);
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(modelValue);
} else {
  this.el.nativeElement.checked = modelValue;
}
```

This is based on https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl#valueAccessor